# How can I stretch a Image displayed on a TGlyph to the size of the TGlyph in a Multi Device Application?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

[image: TGlyph Object]

The `TGlyph` has a `Stretch` boolean value, but on change it does not appear to change anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you set `Stretch = True` the image is stretched but maintains the original aspect ratio.

In your image, the height is the limiting factor. If you change the height of your `TGlyph` you will see that the height of the image also changes (in addition to the width, until it becomes the limiting factor).

`TGlyph` doesn't provide means to change aspect ratio.

---

Edit:

I suggest you try a `TRectangtle` component (under `Shapes` in `Tool Palette`). It has a `Fill` property that you can set to a gradient or bitmap. Maybe the gradient option is ok for you without an image.

But if you set its `Fill.Kind` to `Bitmap` and load a bitmap, you can set its `WrapMode` property to `TileStretch` and then it will grow / shrink **independently** in horizontal and vertical direction.

E.g.:

[image]