# C++ Builder FMX StretchDraw a bitmap to change the size

Tags: c++, bitmap, firemonkey, builder

I notice that in Firemonkey there is no equivalent of StretchDraw for changing the size of a bitmap that I have in memory.

I need to increase the size of a bitmap in memory before displaying it in a TImage Control.  I want the size of the bitmap in memory to match that of a TImage Control before displaying it.  The image bitmap is then sent off to a database blob field.  When I recall the bitmap from the database, it is the original size and not the stretched size that I need.
Tried using Wrapmode and that works great for displaying and stretching the bitmaps in a TImage but It doesn't save the bitmap as stretched.

Any ideas how to do this in C++ Builder?

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68694739/2292722) to a similar question helps. I'm thinking that you replace the `TImageControl` with a `TRectangle` as in the answer of the other post.

Comment: I managed to figure it out. 
You have to setup 2 TRectF variables representing the two different sized bitmaps. 
Then just call DrawBitmap. 
Then assign it to the TImage->Bitmap variable

Comment: You do know that you can answer your own questions, don't you.